# hibernate db2 configuration

Tags: hibernate, properties

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="connection.username">bcmuser</property>
<property name="connection.password">welcome</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:db2://localhost:5003/UNINST</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<mapping class="com.app.mvc.dto.HelloDTO"/>


</session-factory>


</hibernate-configuration>
```

[4/6/17 15:14:06:748 EDT] 00000082 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
[4/6/17 15:14:06:748 EDT] 00000082 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
[4/6/17 15:14:06:748 EDT] 00000082 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
[4/6/17 15:14:06:748 EDT] 00000082 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
[4/6/17 15:14:06:748 EDT] 00000082 SystemErr     R  ... 52 more
[4/6/17 15:14:06:748 EDT] 00000082 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver
[4/6/17 15:14:06:748 EDT] 00000082 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
[4/6/17 15:14:06:748 EDT] 00000082 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:170)
[4/6/17 15:14:06:748 EDT] 00000082 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
[4/6/17 15:14:06:748 EDT] 00000082 SystemErr     R  ... 63 more

Comment: Where is the question we should answer?

Answer (score 0):

Caused by:  SystemErr R Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver

This exception is due to DB2Driver driver. Load DB2Driver jar file on classpath.